# ScalaObjectMapper ClassCastException reading Sequence from json file

Tags: json, scala

I'm deserialising a sequence of objects from a json file with `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper`:

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

case class MyPair(key: String, value:  Double)

mapper.readValue(new File("mypairs.json"), classOf[Seq[MyPair]])
```

`mypairs.json`:

```
[
{"key":"B","value":0.0},
{"key":"C","value":20.0},
{"key":"A","value":30.0}
]
```

This results in:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2 cannot be cast to MyPair
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this with just:

```
mapper.readValue[Seq[MyPair]] (new File("mypairs.json"))
```

The method above is implemented on ScalaObjectMapper
and the one that causes issue

```
public <T> T readValue(File src, Class<T> valueType)
```

is from com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Comment: Similar problem happen when we use Generics based java methods in scala